# Bibtex generates runaway argument

Tags: bibtex

When I try to run pdflatex I get the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
Latex Error: ./texfile.tex:22 File ended while scanning use of \emph .
Latex Error: ./texfile.tex:24 LaTeX Error: \begin{thebibliography} on input line 1 ended by \end{document}.
```

Here is my tex-file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, abstracton]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{longtable}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=3cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\citep{Nawroth:2002zr,Hou:2011vn,Rudini:2008kx,Lampugnani:2006uq,Ishiyama:2010fk,Hudry-Clergeon:2005ys,Angelini:2006vn,Andriopoulou:1999kx,Esser:1998uq,Sun:2012fk,Katsamba:2009kx,Vendome:2011uq,Bennett:1995fk,Ahrens:2003bh,Legrand:2001qf,Harrison:2010ve,Haussinger:2004ly,Parisini:2007zr,Shapiro:1995ys,Patel:2006vn,Boggon:2002kx,Pertz:1999uq,Tamura:1998fk,Cain:2010fk,Taddei:2008ys,Gory-Faure:1999vn,Gulino:1998kx,Gentil-dit-Maurin:2010uq,Corada:2001fk,Breviario:1995vn,Huber:1996uq,Lampugnani:1992fk,Suzuki:1991vn,Larson:2004kx,Breier:1996uq,Potter:2005fk,Tonks:2006fk,Allingham:2007uq,Turowski:2008fk,Vestweber:2012uq,Dejana:2012fk,Harris:2010vn,Huveneers:2012kx,Haidari:2011uq,Nelson:2008fk,Brasch:2011fk,huber:eplin,Abe:2008bh,Kobielak:2004qf,Kametani:2007ve,Drees:2005ly,Pokutta:2000zr,Koslov:1997ys,Rimm:1995vn,Kemler:1989kx,Vestweber:1984uq,Vestweber:1984fk,Lewis:1997fv,Cowin:1986bs,Lampugnani:1995ij,Nelson:2004hc,Orford:1997tg,Aberle:1997kl,Huber:2001oq,Fujita:2002nx,Xiao:2005cr,Huber:2001dq,Huber:1997bh,McCrea:1991ve,McCrea:1991ly,Thoreson:2000zr,Ferber:2002ys,Reynolds:1992vn,Reynolds:1989kx,Reynolds:2004uq,Yonemura:2011fk,Perez-Moreno:2006uq,Pokutta:2007fk,Owen:2008kx,Al-Amoudi:2007uq,He:2003fk,Tsukasaki:2007bh,Leckband:2006qf,Franke:2009ve,Pokutta:2002ly,Tachibana:2000zr,Takai:2008ys,Miyaguchi:2000vn,Hirokawa:1981kx,FARQUHAR:1963uq,Harris:2010fk,Nelson:2008dq,Ogita:2006bh,Ivanov:2001qf,Dejana:2008ve,Yonemura:2010ly,Oda:2011zr,Birukova:2011ys,Giampietro:2012kx,Telo:1998bs,Rampon:2005ij,Bardin:1996hc}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{cell}
\bibliography{bib.bib}

\end{document}
```

And my bib-file is here:

https://gist.github.com/raw/2368d3797ead69cfc6cf/8f75797f1389c1b42c6bfbad71c8ebd01513a40d/bib-file.bib

As far as I understand it a closing bracket is missing in the bib-file, but I cannot find it. The bib-file was generated by BibDesk.
Deleting the citation that causes the problem, also doesn't help. The error resurfaces at another citation.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I took a look in your `.bib` file and detected some problems. First, when you run `bibtex file`, you'll note that the `cell` style complains about the missing `volume` field in 5 or 6 entries - which causes an empty `\emph{` entry in the generated `file.bbl` (the error you pointed out). Filling out out the `volume` field for the entries `bibtex` complains will solve this particular error. Instead of `J{\u}rgen`, use `J\u rgen` (and similar forms) which will solve another issue. `:)` `ctd>>`

Comment: `ctd>>` And at last but not least, don't use symbols like `β` directly in your `.bib` file, since we are using `pdflatex` (`xetex` will allow the direct input), it will raise an error when you compile your file. `:)`

Comment: It appears that BibDesk doesn't quite get the creation of characters with diereses (Umlaute). There are seven instances of `{\a}` that should be `{\"a}`, and six instances of `{\u}` that should be `{\"u}`. There may also be an incorrectly escaped `#` character in the `doi` field of the `Chretien:1998fk` entry. Do make the appropriate global search-and-replace changes in the bib file (or, alternatively check your BibDesk settings and then let BibDesk recreate the bib file from scratch).

Comment: @PauloCereda -- fortunately for the OP, the character `β` only appears to occur in the `abstract` field of several entries. Unless the OP uses a bibliography style that typesets the `abstract` field, the presence of this character shouldn't trouble BibTeX.

Comment: @Mico: ah yes, you are right. `:)` I think `β` only appears in the title of two articles, though there's a bunch of them in the `abstract` fields. `:)`

Comment: Thank you very much Paulo for solving my problem and Mico for your help! I added dummy volume fields and everything is fine know.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but: you are calling the `setspace` package and yet redefining `\baselinestretch` manually.  You clearly don't need to do both, and you should use `setspace` facilities anyway: `\onehalfspacing`. Get rid of your redefinition.

Comment: @jon: thanks for your correction! I changed it :)

Comment: @PauloCereda Would you please write an answer?

Answer (score 5):

By running `bibtex`, we can find some clues of what is happening:

```
$ bibtex mydoc
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (Web2C 2011)
The top-level auxiliary file: mydoc.aux
The style file: cell.bst
Database file #1: mybib.bib
`volume' is a missing field, not a string, for entry Birukova:2011ys
while executing---line 1461 of file cell.bst
`volume' is a missing field, not a string, for entry Dejana:2012fk
while executing---line 1461 of file cell.bst
`volume' is a missing field, not a string, for entry Giampietro:2012kx
while executing---line 1461 of file cell.bst
`volume' is a missing field, not a string, for entry Sun:2012fk
while executing---line 1461 of file cell.bst
`volume' is a missing field, not a string, for entry Vestweber:2012uq
while executing---line 1461 of file cell.bst
(There were 5 error messages)
```

The `cell` style complains about the missing `volume` field in 5 entries, which causes an unclosed `\emph{` entry in the generated `myfile.bbl`, e.g:

```
\bibitem[Dejana and Giampietro, 2012]{Dejana:2012fk}
Dejana, E. and Giampietro, C. (2012{\rm{}}).
\newblock Vascular endothelial-cadherin and vascular stability.
\newblock {\rm Curr Opin Hematol } \emph{.
```

This is the error you pointed out. `:)`

The standard `article` data entry has `volume` as one of the required fields, so we need to declare it, even if we don't have the proper information (it happens sometimes). `:)`

As Mico pointed out, there are some occurences of words with an Umlaut in your `.bib` file which require the correct representation, with `\"a` instead of `\a` and `\"u` instead of `\u` - use `J{\"{u}}rgen` instead of `J{\u}rgen` for correct alphabetizing (thanks egreg). And there seems to be an unescaped `#` symbol in the `doi` field of the `Chretien:1998fk` key which will raise an error if not fixed (thanks Mico).

And at last but not least, don't use the `β` character directly in your `.bib` file (thankfully, it only appears in the title of two or three entries). Since we are using `pdflatex`, it will raise an error when you compile your file. Mico also reminds that `β` appears a lot of times in the `abstract` fields, but since the `cell` style does not use this particular field, you are safe for now. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error message. For me the cause of this error was that several bibtex IDs contained an "_". For example:

```
@Article{balahur2013_sentiment,
  Title                    = {Sentiment analysis in the news},
  ...
}
```

I fixed this by replacing the _ in the ID with something else (I used the - character), e.g.:

```
@Article{balahur2013-sentiment,
  Title                    = {Sentiment analysis in the news},
  ...
}
```

Comment: `_` can be used. Also it does not explain the missing closing brace for `\emph`.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking as well. But do you have any idea about why this actually fixed my problem? I spent hours on this, and finally fixed it by removing all _ characters in the bibtex keys.

Comment: Without  a reproducible example it is hard to tell.